# Summarized Data isn't showing up in ggplot when i graph it

Tags: r, ggplot2, summarize

I have data that I have summarized into weekly arrival amounts. When I go to graph the data, I ggplot doesn't the line for weight.

````
```{r} weightedbyweek = weightedbydate %>% 
group_by(arrival = cut.Date(RECV_DATE, "week")) %>% 
summarise( w = sum(weightdays)) 
```
````

```
ggplot(weightedbyweek, aes(x = arrival, y = w))+ 
  geom_line()
```

All that shows up is the chart with no line for the data in w. I have checked the weightedbyweek data from and there is data for w, which is in difftime.

Comment: When I removed the cut.Date function the graphing worked fine.

Comment: Is this a problem of the wrong [assignment operator](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/assignOps.html)?  You may want to try `<-` instead of `=`.  Are you running those commands on the console or in some document?

Comment: I am running this in an R Markdown document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cut.Date produces a factor by default.
I suspect as.integer(arrival) in the aes will fix it.